# Remote desktop settings grayed out for windows server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, permissions, remote-desktop

I am remotely connected to a box(as an administrator) running windows server 2008. However when I go to system properties >> remote, the options for remote desktop are grayed out. Does anyone know why this might be? I'm trying to change the remote desktop setting to only allow connections from computers running Remote Desktop with Network Level Authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. Does anyone know what group policy setting this is related to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is in Group Policy, in Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Session Host -> Security.  The policy is "Require user authentication for remote connections by using Network Level Authentication."

Comment: The item 'Remote Desktop Session\Connections\Allow users to connect remotely using Remote Desktop Services' can also be relevant, as noted [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/forefront/en-US/bb8256e2-d2d9-4388-818f-d0f676034522/windows-10-allow-remote-desktop-access-grayed-out-and-wont-let-me-change-options?forum=win10itprovirt)

Answer (score 0):

Group policy denying you from changing these settings.
open gpedit.msc and remove restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Group Policy deciding what those settings are for you.